# Flutter exception `setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build` by calling setState in a NotificationListener callback

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having an hard time trying to figure out how to update a piece of a view based on a child view "event"... let me explain:

I have a screen which is composed by a `Scaffold`, having as a `body` a custom widget which calls a rest api to get the data to display (it makes use of a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)), then it dispatch a [Notification](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Notification-class.html) (which basically wraps the Flutter's [AsynchSnapshot](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html)) that should be used in order to update the `floatingActionButton` (at least in my mind :P).

This is the `build` method of the screen:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NotificationListener<MyNotification>(
      onNotification: onMyNotification,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: MyAppBar(),
        body: MyRemoteObjectView(),
        floatingActionButton: MyFloatingButton(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The view is rendered perfectly, the data is retrieved from the server and displayed by `MyRemoteObjectView` and the notification is successfully dispatched and received, BUT as soon as I call `setState()` in my callback, I get the exception:

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

This is the callback (defined in the same class of the `build` method above):

```
bool onMyNotification(MyNotification notification) {
    AsyncSnapshot snapshot = notification.snapshot;

    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      setState(() {
        // these flags are used to customize the appearance and behavior of the floating button
        _serverHasBeenCalled = true;
        _modelDataRetrieved = snapshot.hasData;
      });
    }

    return true;
}
```

This is the point in which I send the notification (build method of `MyRemoteObjectView`'s state):

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<T>(
      future: getData(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<T> snapshot) {
        MyNotification(snapshot).dispatch(context);
        // ...
```

The point is: **how** and **when** should I tell Flutter to redraw the floating button (and/or other widgets)? (because of course without the `setState` I don't have the exception but the button is not refreshed)

Am I getting the whole thing wrong? Is there an easier way to do it? Let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After *FutureBuilder* is built, it waits for future to return a value. After it is complete, you're calling *setState* and then *FutureBuilder* would be built again and so on, resulting in infinite repaint loop.

Are you sure that you need FutureBuilder and NotificationListener in this case? You should probably do it in *initState* of your StatefulWidget like this:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();

  getData().then((data) {
    setState(() {
      _serverHasBeenCalled = true;
      _modelDataRetrieved = true;
    });
  });
}
```

You can also store *Future* in a state and pass it to *FutureBuilder*.